# Dell Factory reset of W7 from W10 preview

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Laptop originally shipped with a legit Win7.

I wanted to try Windows 10 Tech Preview, so I uninstalled W7 and installed W10TP on top of it (I am giving the PC to someone else, so it's the perfect occasion to do that).

Now, I would like to switch back to my original W7 so I can recover my genuine licence, and perform the free W10 upgrade.

However, I cannot find a way to restore the factory image. I have checked my disk and I still have a 14.65 GB "Recovery" partition, which I believe contains this factory image.

I have tried the W10 procedure from [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297920#WinRE) but when I go to the troobleshoot menu, there is no such "Factory Image Reset" option (I believe it's only visible for Dells shipped with W10 already).

I don't have the disk, the laptop was shipped with OS preinstalled. For info, it's a Dell N5010.

So what should I do to perform this factory reset ?

Comment: Oh right, I just realized the presence of this COA under by laptop. I'm not sure about what you mean "Windows 10 has already been activated on your device". I only installed the W10 Techical Preview, but the "final" version has not been activated, and according to some sources my comp may stop booting around the   10/15/15 ?

So can I install W10 with this COA license code, or do I have to reinstall the same version W7 mentionned on the COA ?

Comment: On the bottom-right hand corner it says `Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Evaluation copy. Build 10525`, I'm supposed to retrograde ?

Comment: Hmm right sorry, what I read was about a previous build. But my main goal was still to perform a complete system restore and get rid of all apps/data. I will go with your suggestion of a manual reinstal of W7. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, how about "Restore your Dell computer to the Dell factory image using recovery media" which is right after that?

This may help you get the recovery media: http://dslbdownload.datasafelocalbackup.com/dsldownload-en.html

Comment: During installation, I have an error message `Dell DataSafe Local Backup cannot be installed because your Hard Drive does not have the Windows Recovery Environment`

Comment: Sorry, can't help you more. And whoever downvotes for no reason should just... Anyhow, I can only wish you good luck, and hopefully someone more experienced will chip in.

Comment: Yeah downvotes without explanation really suck... Thanks anyway for your suggestion.